# On ng serve I receive this error: ERROR in Error: Internal Error: The name element is already defined in scope to be [object Object]

Tags: angular, migration

```
Angular CLI: 10.0.4
Node: 12.13.0
OS: linux x64
Angular: 10.0.7
... animations, common, compiler, `compiler-cli`, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router
Ivy Workspace: Yes
Package                           Version
@angular-devkit/architect         0.1000.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.1000.4
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.1000.4
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.1000.4
@angular-devkit/core              10.0.4
@angular-devkit/schematics        10.0.4
@angular/cdk                      10.1.1
@angular/cli                      10.0.4
@angular/material                 10.1.1
@ngtools/webpack                  10.0.4
@schematics/angular               10.0.4
@schematics/update                0.1000.4
rxjs                              6.6.2
typescript                        3.9.7
webpack                           4.43.0
```

On running ng serve I receive an error:

```
 ERROR in Error: Internal Error: The name element is already defined in scope to be [object Object]
    at error (/home/marcel/workspace/cts-frontend/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:2918:15)
    at BindingScope.set (/home/marcel/workspace/cts-frontend/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:18913:17)
    at TemplateDefinitionBuilder.registerContextVariables (/home/marcel/workspace/cts-frontend/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:17791:32)
    at /home/marcel/workspace/cts-frontend/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:17702:59
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at TemplateDefinitionBuilder.buildTemplateFunction (/home/marcel/workspace/cts-frontend/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:17702:23)
    at /home/marcel/workspace/cts-frontend/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:18291:60
    at /home/marcel/workspace/cts-frontend/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:17728:81
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at TemplateDefinitionBuilder.buildTemplateFunction (/home/marcel/workspace/cts-frontend/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:17728:37)
    at Object.compileComponentFromMetadata (/home/marcel/workspace/cts-frontend/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:19406:58)
    at ComponentDecoratorHandler.compile (/home/marcel/workspace/cts-frontend/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/annotations/src/component.js:537:34)
    at _loop_2 (/home/marcel/workspace/cts-frontend/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/transform/src/compilation.js:554:53)
    at TraitCompiler.compile (/home/marcel/workspace/cts-frontend/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/transform/src/compilation.js:584:21)
    at IvyCompilationVisitor.visitClassDeclaration (/home/marcel/workspace/cts-frontend/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/transform/src/transform.js:53:43)
    at /home/marcel/workspace/cts-frontend/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/util/src/visitor.js:81:83
```

Comment: about what this error can be?

Comment: you probably declared a variable which has already been declared in the same block

you may find this link for answers: 
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/35369#issuecomment-589533893

Comment: thank you, I will investigate, but it's a big project. :-)

Comment: for me, I use VS code and used the find all functionality of it and type the name of the variable (e.g. 'let myVariableName') that causes the error. and luckily found it declared twice in the *ngFor directive and removed those

Comment: @ajgo I search in my html code and I removed any code that has the ```let i``` and still the i get the error

Comment: is 'i' variable declared twice in the element? I think you must look for elements with *ngFor directives that has something like: <div *ngFor="let i of list; let element =...; let element = ...">...</div> where 'element' variable is declared twice that causes the error

Answer (score 2):

It happens usually when you are using same variable twice in same block.

for me it was in ngFor i was used twice.

```
<div *ngFor="let i in winners; let i=index></div>
```

Error: The i element is already defined in scope to be [object Object], here it is saying i is used twice.

Similary for your case

Error: The name element is already defined in scope to be [object Object], here check for name variable.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this exact same issue. ng serve will not give you enough info as you'll just get the useless error in the console. However, If you do a `ng build --prod` that type of build will tell you exactly what file the issue is in. I'm using the Angular 11.1 compiler in case that matters.

Answer (score 0):

I had the following issue:

```
<ng-template let-data pTemplate="body" let-data let-columns="columns">
    <tr [pSelectableRow]="data" (dblclick)="doubleClick(data)">
      <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
        <div *ngIf="col.header === 'Some Date' || col.header === 'Some Date2'">
          <span class="ui-column-title">{{ col.header }}</span>
          {{ data[col.field] | date: 'shortDate' }}
       </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
```

As you can see

> let-data

is written twice. I removed one of the definitions and it compiled correctly.